# Get image of a post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a slide show in wordpress, I made a category for it and now I want to get images of that category for my slide show. Here is part of my code:

```
<div id="slide-show">
   <ul>
        <?php query_posts('cat=1'); while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <img src="<?php
            $image=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail');
            echo $image[0];?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" /></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it does not work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What is not working? Is the list being parsed but src attribute empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'll [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978350/1287812) myself:

> First of all, **don't use** `query_posts`.
>   Please, check:
>
> - [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)
> - [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/12615)

---

In this case, I'd suggest building a function to create the desired output. You put it inside your theme `functions.php` file. Put it at the end of the file.
If there is any `?>` as the last thing of a PHP file, **remove it**, it is not necessary and may break your site if there is any white space *after it*.

That said, our function will print exactly the Html you want and it is called like this in **any** theme template file (`index.php`, `single.php`, `page.php`, etc).

```
<?php get_gallery(4); ?>
```

The number 4 is the Category ID.

And this is the function, check the comments in the code:

```
function get_gallery( $id )
{
    // Simple query
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'category' => $id, 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
    ) );

    // Start building the Html code
    $slide_show = '
        <div id="slide-show">
            <ul>';

    // Iterate through the results
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        // Assign value and test if it exists at the *same time*
        if( $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) )
        {
            $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb );

            // Build the Html elements
            $slide_show .= '
                <li>
                    <a href="' . $permalink . '">
                    <img src="'. $image[0] . '" alt="' . $post->post_title .'" />
                    </a>
                </li>';
        }
    }

    // Finish the Html
    $slide_show .= '
            </ul>
        </div>
    ';

    // Print the Html
    echo $slide_show;
}
```

**Result:**
[image: html output screenshot]